# Hash function SHA1 in C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, openssl, sha1

I want to use `SHA1` function from *openssl* library for hashing a string, I have downloaded the library and installed it in `/usr/include`, and here is my code:

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char string[] = "hello world";

    SHA1((unsigned char*) &string, strlen(string), (unsigned char*) &digest);
}
```

It doesn't have any syntax error and it recognizes openssl/sha.h, but when I want to build the project in eclipse or build from the terminal, I get this error:

```
Hash.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `SHA1'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: So you need to link against the library. What is the command you are using to build from the terminal?

Answer (score 5):

You didn't properly link `openssl`, if you're on Linux, you should link `crypto`.

*From a terminal* :

```
g++ -o hash hash.cpp -lcrypto
```

*From eclipse*, you should open `project->Properties`, go to `C/C++ Build->Settings` and add `crypto` in the `Linker->Libraries` folder.